# Convert Column Type to Long Text in Access

Tags: ms-access

I am running a query in Access 2013.

```
SELECT short, long INTO newTbl
FROM tbl
```

My problem is that long is a 1000 characters and by default newTbl treats it as Short Text. I can edit the field in Design View and change the type to Long Text, but when I rerun the query, it switches back to Short Text. Is there something I can add to my query so it automatically becomes Long Text?

Comment: Perhaps run CREATE TABLE first where you can define the field types. Then run INSERT INTO table (SELECT...)

Answer (score 0):

I ran into a similar issue today. The workaround I'm using is an aggregate function 'First'. For this purpose try something like:

```
SELECT tbl.short, First(tbl.long) AS FirstOflong INTO newTbl 
FROM tbl GROUP BY tbl.short, tbl.long;
```